# Can Gnuplot use Pandoc tables as data?

Tags: gnuplot, pandoc

Pandoc table example which I use in my incomplete LaTeX files

```
-------------------------------------------------
File        Byte        Chars           Lines
-------     ---------   -----------     ---------
009         24152000    24152000        72456000

001         24152000    24152000        72456000

000         24103840    24103840        72311520

0000        193360      193360          580080

0001        241520      241520          724560

0002        241520      241520          724560
-------------------------------------------------
```

Gnuplot would accept

```
File        Byte        Chars           Lines
009         24152000    24152000        72456000
001         24152000    24152000        72456000
000         24103840    24103840        72311520
0000        193360      193360          580080
0001        241520      241520          724560
0002        241520      241520          724560
```

I would like to do gnuplots directly from my notes.

How can you use incomplete Pandoc tables as a data source for gnuplot? 
It would be great if some option for this exists but I have not found any.

Comment: what does the source of the latex/incomplete pandoc table look like?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic It is the first table in the body of question.

Comment: I got that, thx..is what the actual data in the source file looks like?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic Source file is binary. These numbers are about its computational behavior.

Comment: gnuplot has **every** and **using** syntax to ignore some lines. Have you tried that syntax first? For examples, try **help every** at the gnuplot prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` to remove the empty lines and the lines starting with at least 7 dashes with the following command

```
awk '!/(^\s*$|^-{7,})/' data.dat
```

The regular expression matches on all lines which contain only white spaces or begin with at least seven dashes.

You can also call this command on-the-fly from gnuplot with

```
plot '< awk ''!/(^\s*$|^-{7,})/'' data.dat' skip 1
```

Th doubled single quotes around the regex are the way you must escape single quotes inside other single quotes with gnuplot. And using single quotes prevents the need to escape the backslashes in the regex.

The `skip 1` ignores the first line. Maybe you want to use that in some other way (e.g. for the key).

Comment: WOOT! I did not know that you can incorporate AWK in gnuplot.

Comment: Yes, thats basically the way to go if you have need for some external processing. I use this quite often to read data from hdf5 files with `plot '< h5totxt ...`, or uncompressing ASCII files on the fly with `plot '< gzip -c -d ...'`, or for filtering when the `1/0` trick doesn't work, like when you want to connect only a subset of your data with lines.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pandoc scripting](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html). You'll have to write a script that matches on all the `Table` nodes in the AST of the pandoc document and generates a format Gnuplot can read (csv is probably easier to generate).

Or you can use `pandoc -t json` to get a JSON representation of the AST and do the scripting like that. With the current Pandoc version (1.14), your [sample would produce](http://pandoc.org/try/?text=-------------------------------------------------%0AFile++++++++Byte++++++++Chars+++++++++++Lines%0A-------+++++---------+++-----------+++++---------%0A009+++++++++24152000++++24152000++++++++72456000%0A%0A001+++++++++24152000++++24152000++++++++72456000%0A%0A000+++++++++24103840++++24103840++++++++72311520%0A%0A0000++++++++193360++++++193360++++++++++580080%0A%0A0001++++++++241520++++++241520++++++++++724560%0A%0A0002++++++++241520++++++241520++++++++++724560%0A-------------------------------------------------&from=markdown&to=json) the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "unMeta": {}
    },
    [
        {
            "t": "Table",
            "c": [
                [],
                [
                    {
                        "t": "AlignLeft",
                        "c": []
                    },
                    {
                        "t": "AlignLeft",
                        "c": []
                    },
                    {
                        "t": "AlignLeft",
                        "c": []
                    },
                    {
                        "t": "AlignLeft",
                        "c": []
                    }
                ],
                [
                    0.15,
                    0.15,
                    0.2,
                    0.1125
                ],
                [
                    [
                        {
                            "t": "Plain",
                            "c": [
                                {
                                    "t": "Str",
                                    "c": "File"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "t": "Plain",
                            "c": [
                                {
                                    "t": "Str",
                                    "c": "Byte"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "t": "Plain",
                            "c": [
                                {
                                    "t": "Str",
                                    "c": "Chars"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "t": "Plain",
                            "c": [
                                {
                                    "t": "Str",
                                    "c": "Lines"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "009"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "24152000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "24152000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "72456000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "001"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "24152000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "24152000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "72456000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "24103840"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "24103840"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "72311520"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "0000"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "193360"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "193360"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "580080"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "0001"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "241520"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "241520"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "724560"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "0002"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "241520"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "241520"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "t": "Plain",
                                "c": [
                                    {
                                        "t": "Str",
                                        "c": "724560"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: @Masi posted (long) link in answer :) it's not exactly pretty, but it's JSON.

Comment: Please, include the content of the link here too.